# I'm trying to create a float array with numpy but i'm getting object array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to multiply two arrays but I could not do it, i get this exception:

"TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported"

and apparently when I create one of the two arrays i get a dtype=object array and not a dtype=float as it should be.

these are the arrays that I want to multiply in this way:

```py
A = np.array([[.9, .07, .01],
             [0, .93, .05, .02],
            [0, .0, .85, .15],
             [0, 0, 0, 1.00]])

X = np.array([[85, 10, 5, 0]])

print(A.T @ X.T) # this generates the exception mentioned above
```

when i print the "A" array i get this:

```
array([list([0.9, 0.07, 0.01]), list([0, 0.93, 0.05, 0.02]),
       list([0, 0.0, 0.85, 0.15]), list([0, 0, 0, 1.0])], dtype=object)
```

and I guess that's the reason of the error

I do not understand why there are list inside the array and looks like it is an object type (dtype=object), i need and float array of (4,3) shape but i get and (4,) shape.

How could I solve this? How could I create an float array that can be multiplied

i'm using numpy==1.15.4 and python 3.6

thank you

Comment: your array A first row , have 3 item only

Comment: All sublists need to have the same number of elements.  One has 3, the others 4.

Comment: thank you very much, that was the reason, it was a great carelessness of mine that made me lose a lot of time